# Unable to add a bounty to a question

Tags: discussion, bounty

I was trying to add a bounty to Lawrence Cayton's [question on exact near neighbors](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7844/exact-nearest-neighbor-in-d-dimensional-euclidean-space), but I can nowhere see the link to start a bounty. I've looked at other questions and didn't have a problem seeing the link, so I'm wondering if this is a problem with my machine/browser or is a generic problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to wait for two days after the question is posted to set a bounty.

Answer (score 4):

See the bullets at the bottom of

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

For the basic set of rules around bounties. There's also more detail at

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)